# How do i get rid of "dropped off bottom" in my MARS compiler when I run this program?

Tags: assembly, mips

```
#program for inputting an integer and displaying it.

.data
    prompt:  .asciiz "Enter a number: "
    message: .asciiz "\nNumber entered is: "

.text
    li $v0, 4  #prompts the user to enter an integer.
    la $a0, prompt
    syscall


    li $v0, 5   # Reads in the integer
    syscall
    #Store the integer in $t0 since we need $v0 free
    move $t0,$v0

#Display message now.

    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, message     #prints the variable message.
    syscall

#Display the integer

    li $v0, 1
    move $a0,$t0        #move the contents of $t0 into the argument register.
    syscall
```

Comment: You need an exit syscall at the end.

Comment: Also, I cannot find any good websites to learn Assembly lang from. If y'all know any please do comment below. If you think the program is written in a bad form please point that out too since I just started with this language.

Comment: Code looks fine, and has sensible comments.

Answer (score 2):

You just simply need to add a syscall 10 at the end

```
li $v0, 10
syscall
```

A syscall with 10 in the $v0 register tells the computer that the program is done. So in your case you would want to have something like

```
.data
    prompt:  .asciiz "Enter a number: "
    message: .asciiz "\nNumber entered is: "

.text
    li $v0, 4  #prompts the user to enter an integer.
    la $a0, prompt
    syscall


    li $v0, 5   # Reads in the integer
    syscall
    #Store the integer in $t0 since we need $v0 free
    move $t0,$v0

    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, message     #prints the variable message.
    syscall

    li $v0, 1
    move $a0,$t0        #move the contents of $t0 into the argument register.
    syscall

    li $v0, 10          # Signal end of program
    syscall
```

you can even just have it under a label like end. That way whenever you want to end the program you can branch to end and then finishing code will be executed

```
end:
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```

Comment: *under a function head* - you mean "label".  If you just `beq end` for example, that's just a normal branch, not a function call.  You *could* look at it as a tailcall to a noreturn function (which doesn't care about getting a return address in `$ra`), but it makes more sense to just think of it as a conditional goto to a label.